# I am confused with the use of FormBean and DTO in Struts

Tags: java, struts

As I asked I am problem with using DTO,I want to extract data from FormBean and put it into DTO and vice versa,but I don't know the correct way to do it.

please help me related to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the properties of your form and your DTO have matching names then you will find this very useful in you actions, works also for map backed forms:

org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtil.copyProperties(Object dest,Object orig)